# Spring PropertySource doesn't do anything

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm attempting to read from a property file using Spring 4.1. My class looks more or less like the official [example](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) and I'd like to autowire it into my other classes.

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "file:C:/asd1.properties")
public class PropertiesUtil {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public String getStuff() {
        return env.getProperty("stuff");
    }
}
```

and

```java
@Autowired
private PropertiesUtil propertiesUtil;
public void setPropertiesUtil(PropertiesUtil propertiesUtil) {
    this.propertiesUtil = propertiesUtil;
}
```

However, the PropertySource annotation is seemingly ignored. I can breakpoint in `getStuff()` and `env` exists, but `getProperty` returns null. Also, Spring doesn't complain if the file actually doesn't exist.

What am I missing?

Comment: This example worked for me. Posting my code.

Comment: My fault was that I only executed this code from my tests and forgot to add the PropertiesUtil class to the ContextConfiguration:
```@ContextConfiguration(classes = {PropertiesUtil.class})```

Answer (score 0):

1) Content of property file:

```
stuff=hello
```

2) Spring-config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.concept" />

<bean id="test" class="com.spring.concept.Testing" />

</beans>
```

3) Testing.java

```
package com.spring.concept;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class Testing {

@Autowired
private PropertiesUtil propertiesUtil;
public void setPropertiesUtil(PropertiesUtil propertiesUtil) {
    this.propertiesUtil = propertiesUtil;
}

public void print(){
    System.out.println("Hello world!!");
    System.out.println(propertiesUtil.getStuff());
}

}
```

4) PropertiesUtil.java similar to what you posted.
5) In pom.xml, added these two dependencies

```
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
<version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

5) Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
        Testing test=(Testing)ctx.getBean("test");
        test.print();

    }
```

6) Output:
Hello world!!
hello

Check

```
<context:component-scan>
```

in your spring config file and content of asd1.properties file.